# How to properly color in C# GDI+?

Tags: c#, colors, 3d, gdi+

I have this assignment where I need to create a Rotating 3D Castle with Color using C# GDI+. 
I crammed and decided to download an already-built program here:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/3D-Modeling-using-GDI-b93937b9

I replaced the shape in VectorShape.cs with my vertices, edges and faces.
Also, I've put some additional code to make the shape colored.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            Point[] point2D = new Point[m_face[i].Length]; //I added this
            //iterate each edges in that face
            for (int j = 0; j < m_face[i].Length; j++)
            {

                int k=m_face[i][j];

                GraphicsState _s1 = g.Save();
                GraphicsContainer a = g.BeginContainer();
                Point3d p1 =m_vertex[m_edges[k][0]];
                Point3d p2 = m_vertex[m_edges[k][1]];
                double[] _p1 = ProjMatrix.ApplyTransform(p1.X,p1.Y,p1.Z, 1);
                double[] _p2 = ProjMatrix.ApplyTransform(p2.X, p2.Y, p2.Z, 1);
                P1.X = (int)_p1[0]; P1.Y = -(int)_p1[1];
                P2.X = (int)_p2[0]; P2.Y = -(int)_p2[1];

                point2D[j].X = P2.X; //I added this
                point2D[j].Y = P2.Y; //I added this
                g.DrawLine(m_pen,P1, P2);
                g.ResetTransform();
                g.EndContainer(a); 
                g.Restore(_s1);
            }
            g.FillPolygon(Brushes.Gray, point2D); //I added this.
        }
```

Both the front and back faces are okay but when rendering the sides, the top and the bottom face, the coloring looked like these:
[Badly Colored Side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sqt9S.png) [Badly Colored Castle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zosvw.png)

I've tried to color the cube that came with the program. The output was similar. The front and back faces were alright. The other faces were bad. So, I think the problem is the code where I downloaded it. I've already tried using similar GDI+ programs but this is the only one where you can manually put vertices, edges and faces. I also can't build a program from scratch because I've got little knowledge about 3D stuff, honestly.

Comment: Are you building the polygons all the same direction? So looking at the front face, it's always builded clockwise? The determination on the front- and backside are done by checking the clockwise or counterclockwise buildup [Curve orientation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_orientation)

Comment: It looks as if the sides/faces are not properly separated. The code seems ok, though. Try this: use a different color for each face to see where those wrong portions are created.

Comment: @TaW Forgive me if I didn't understand but, I tried that and the wrong portions came from the face itself.

Comment: @J. van Langen I really don't have an idea what direction the polygons are being built, but it does seem that the front and back faces are built at the same direction.

Comment: @EmeraldsrsThey should have been the opposite. Because it's _useless_ to draw the backside. One should been gray, the other should be white.

Comment: _the wrong portions came from the face itself._ So the images show only one face each??

Comment: Where is the Graphics `g` created?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Antialiasing SmoothingMode

```
mygraphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
```